# bootstrap grid system and fixed sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

I am trying to create bootstrap grid page with two main sections. one is the app content and the other one is side nav bar.
the nav bar is much shorter the the app content itself. what i am trying to accomplish is that whenever i scroll the page, the app side nav bat will always stick to the top of the page (top, not bottom of it)

my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
      <app-content></app-content>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <app-side-navbar></app-side-navbar>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

whenever i scroll the page, i want to always see on the top right corner the app navbar.

thanks!

Comment: nope, I forget to mention that above this row there is another component which is the header. your solution puts the side bar over the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what solved the issue for me:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <app-content></app-content>
      </div>

      <div class="sticky">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <app-side-navbar></app-side-navbar>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/NMXBaO).

Comment: Had the same issue and found this thread here on StackOverflow! Worked nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try use `fixed`

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
      <app-content></app-content>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-sticky">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <app-side-navbar></app-side-navbar>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in css:

```
.nav-sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: nope, I forget to mention that above this row there is another component which is the header. your solution puts the side bar over the header.

Comment: do you want the header sticky too?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `overflow: auto` for content wrapper only

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 content">
      <div class='col-md-12 wrapper'>
        Content
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 800px;
}
```

Let me know for more details

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your app container

```
min-height:100vh;
max-height:100vh;
overflow:scroll;
```

Give `position:fixed` to your `row`.
Added header to my sample as well.

```css
.app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.row {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.navigator {}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">

      <div class="col-sm-8 app">
        APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/> APP CONTENT
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>APP CONTENT
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 navigator">
        NAVBAR
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your header fixed as well?